# Script for exporting 3d objects for Direct3D?

Tags: graphics, scripting, 3d, directx

I've been reading Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11. Great title.

I would like to know, is there a script for exporting meshes, from standard 3D software, in the format bellow:

```
VertexCount: 31076
TriangleCount: 60339
VertexList (pos, normal)
{
    0.592978 1.92413 -2.62486 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
    0.571224 1.94331 -2.66948 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
    0.609047 1.90942 -2.58578 0.572276 0.816877 0.0721907
    ...
}
TriangleList
{
    0 1 2
    3 4 5
    6 7 8
    ...
}
```

Comment: That looks like an absolutely dreadful format for storing large amounts of mesh data. And it's by no means "the format" for D3D. I mean nothing's stopping you from using that, but don't fool yourself into thinking it's in any way smart or required.

Comment: @Blindy Can you suggest another ways of storing and loading meshes into D3D?

Comment: If you want a simple text human-readable format, try Wavefront OBJ. See [DirectXMesh](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh) for details and code, in particularly the wiki page [Geometry formats](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXMesh/wiki/Geometry-formats).